# Amazon S3 setting metadata fails using AWS SDK PHP v2 upload()

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having problems setting the "Metadata" option when uploading files to Amazon S3 using the AWS SDK PHP v2. The [documentation that I'm reading](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_upload) for the upload() method states that the the 5th parameter is an array of options...

> *$options Custom options used when executing commands: - params: Custom
>   parameters to use with the upload. **The parameters must map to a
>   PutObject** or InitiateMultipartUpload operation parameters. -
>   min_part_size: Minimum size to allow for each uploaded part when
>   performing a multipart upload. - concurrency: Maximum number of
>   concurrent multipart uploads. - before_upload: Callback to invoke
>   before each multipart upload. The callback will receive a
>   Guzzle\Common\Event object with context.*

My `upload()` code looks like this..

```
$upload = $client->upload(
  '<BUCKETNAME>',
  'metadatatest.upload.jpg',
  fopen('metadatatest.jpg','r'),
  'public-read',
  array('Metadata' => array(
    'SomeKeyString' => 'SomeValueString'
  ))
);
```

...and no meta data is set after upload.

If however I use `putObject()` [as documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject), which I assume is a "lower level" method compared to `upload()`...

```
$putObject = $client->putObject(
  array(
    'Bucket' => '<BUCKETNAME>',
    'Key' => 'metadatatest.putobject.jpg',
    'Body' => file_get_contents('metadatatest.jpg'),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'Metadata' => array(
      'SomeKeyString' => 'SomeValueString'
    )
  )
);
```

The meta data is successfully returned when I call `getObject()` or view the file directly in my browser when uploaded using `putObject()`

```
$getObject = $client->getObject(
  array(
    'Bucket' => '<BUCKETNAME>',
    'Key' => 'metadatatest.putobject.jpg'
  )
);
```

I would prefer to use the `$client->upload()` method as the documentation states

> *Upload a file, stream, or string to a bucket. If the upload size exceeds the specified threshold, the upload will be performed using
>   parallel multipart uploads.*

I'm not sure what I've missed?

Comment: This seems like it could be a bug. Please report it at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues. I would also mention the size of the objects you are uploading, because it may only be an issue with multipart uploads.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom Cheers I'll give that avenue a shot, The file was quite small as `putObject()` handles it fine.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom This isn't really a code bug, but a problem with how the documentation for that method is written. I also found it to be confusing until I looked at the actual source code. Maybe you guys can improve it with some examples that will clarify things.

Comment: @dcro Ah, I can see how that can be confusing. Noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no difference in using `upload()` or `putObject()` if you don't do multipart uploads. You can have a look at the [AWS PHP SDK source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php) but basically the `upload` method just calls `putObject` like this:

```
// Perform a simple PutObject operation
return $this->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'Body'   => $body,
    'ACL'    => $acl
) + $options['params']);
```

This isn't very clear in the SDK documentation, but you need to send the last parameter as an array with the key `params` and its value being a second array with the `Metadata` key and value like this:

```
$upload = $client->upload(
    '<BUCKETNAME>',
    'metadatatest.upload.jpg',
    fopen('metadatatest.jpg','r'),
    'public-read',
    array('params' => array(
        'Metadata' => array(
            'SomeKeyString' => 'SomeValueString'
    )))
);
```

However, I you could just use the putObject call to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Fantastic, that explains it perfectly @dcro, I actually ended up switching to using the `UploadBuilder::newInstance()` which did help with the clarity a bit.

Comment: Actually... I just looked at the source code you linked to and it will call `putObject()` when its within the constraints of `if ($body->getSize() < $options['min_part_size'])` otherwise it will perform a `UploadBuilder::newInstance` call, so with your clarification of the `params` array I am now safe to use the `upload()` method.

Comment: That's correct. If you don't specify a value for `min_part_size`, the default value is 5MB.